# Lenovo Thinkpad Thunderbolt 4 Dock Not Working

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo, thunderbolt

This seems to be a very common issue, with rare resolution, but here goes.

Laptop: Dell XPS 9360
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-7560U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4
GPU: Mesa Intel® Iris(R) Plus Graphics 640 (Kaby Lake GT3e) (KBL GT3)
Dock: Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 4 Workstation Dock

I'm tearing my hair out trying to get the dock to play ball with my laptop.

It should be noted that the Thunderbolt cable the dock came with is a split cable, but my other laptop (Windows) runs fine with just one end in the power jack.  To THIS laptop, however, that cable does absolutely nothing.  No recognition, no reaction, nada.

I do also have a Lenovo Hybrid USBC to USBA cable that I tried, specifically this guy:
https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/cables-and-adapters/cables/4x90u90618

With that cable, it gets closer, but still not working optimally. Specifically, if I plug it into the laptop's USB port, then the hardware plugged into the dock like the mouse, keyboard, etc, are recognized and work fine - HOWEVER, the dock itself still does not show up in Thunderbolt settings, and the monitors are not receiving a signal.

BUT, if I use that cable to plug directly into the laptop's power port, it ALMOST seems to be working perfectly - and then keeps intermittently disconnecting.

I'm positive that I'm going to get a few suggestions that I've already tried based on research, but I still welcome all of them.  Maybe I even did one of them wrong, who knows?

Last thing that could be of note - this laptop is dual boot, with Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you elaborate on "I'm positive that I'm going to get a few suggestions that I've already tried"? It would be unfortunate if someone were to invest a good deal of time writing a detailed answer only to hear "Did that. Didn't work." 

Comment: Sounds like the port does not have enough power.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install DisplayLink sofware for Ubuntu.

https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/usb-c

It's well supported for Lenovo docking solutions.

Comment: Works for me on ubuntu 22.04, actually this link: https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu